# Cisco VoIP telephony - Can't save Night Service Bell Configuration

Tags: cisco, voip, telephony

When trying to save "Night Service Bell Configuration" settings under Cisco Unified Communications Manager Express the following error message pops up.

```
Configuration change failed. 
Please report the following error: Invalid ITS command option.
```

Am logged in to the console as admin.

Below is the error alert which pops up when I click change.  What does this mean and how can I fix it?

[image: Night Service Bell Configuration]